# Linux Background PHP process

Tags: linux, php

Ok, this seems really weird.  When I am running a php script from the command line with `&` at the end to run it in the background, it's immediately stopped. I tried it on another server and it worked as expected; the job is running in the background.

The PHP

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
sleep (5);
```

Output on Server 1

```
[mk@li89-44 html]# ./test.php &
[1] 4938
[mk@li89-44 html]# jobs
[1]+  Running        ./test.php &
```

Output on Server 2

```
[mk@dev html]# ./test.php &
[1] 4938
[mk@dev html]# jobs
[1]+  Stopped        ./test.php &
```

On Server 2, I can get it in the background like so:

```
[mk@dev html]$ ./test.php
ctrl + z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./test.php
[mk@dev html]$ bg
[1]+ ./test.php &
[mk@dev html]$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 ./test.php
```

Also on Server 2, if i do something like `wget "http://fileserver.com/largefile.gz" &` it goes into the bg running as expected. Running `nohup ./test.php &` on server 2 also works as expected.

Both servers are running centos, different versions, and different versions of php as well.  I dunno if that's relevant, or if this can be explained just by the way `jobs`, `fg`, `bg` work on linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at an `strace` of the process, you can see that PHP always initializes the terminal, which requires waiting for PHP to control the terminal:

```
ioctl(0, TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = ? ERESTARTSYS
--- {si_signo=SIGTTOU, si_code=SI_KERNEL} (Stopped (tty output)) ---
--- Stopped (tty output) by SIGTTOU ---
```

A simple workaround:

> ./test.php > /dev/null &

Comment: Hmmm... even with the `> /dev/null &` it still goes into the jobs queue as stopped.

Comment: Then you may need to `strace` it yourself and see what it's doing. If it's accessing standard input, for example, you may need a `< /dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you have installed php-cli package?

check to if `/usr/bin/php` is a path of the binary, different distributions use different paths.

Comment: ya, it's not that it wont run, it runs fine, i just cant background it with `&`